# Can I include variable in string formatting mini-language (Python)?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to convert numbers into binary strings with a specified length in python. In my function, the length `N` is a variable, so I tried `f'{3:Nb}'`, where 3 is just some random numbers. However, it returns `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`. Is there a way I can include the variable in this string formatting mini-language? Thanks!

Comment: try this: `f'{3:{N}b}'`

Comment: @HIMANSHU PANDEY Thank you!